# C# Wpf How to Change Listviewitem's Height Using a Button in it?

Tags: c#, wpf, height, listviewitem

I have listview items that contains 1 button in it. Listview item's default height is 60.

When i click listview item's button, that row(contains the button clicked)'s height should change to 100. When i click that button again row's height should change back to 60.

I'm really can't find out how to implement this.

[image]
When i click Row1's details button, Row1's height should change to 100. If i click it again it's heigth should change back to 60.

I'm adding buttons to listview items like this :

```
                 <GridViewColumn >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>                                  
                               <ButtonName="DetailsButton"Content="Details"FontWeight="Bold"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="520,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="25">
                               </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: should use a `ToggleButton`, then you can toggle the row's height when togglebutton's Checked state changes (via binding)

Comment: How do you populate the Listview? Do you use databinding (bind ListView's ItemsSource to a data source), or do you add the rows one by one in a for loop?

Comment: I'm using databinding to populate Listview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may use DataTemplate `Triggers` to achieve the same

sample

```
<GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ToggleButton Name="DetailsButton"
                              Content="Details"
                              FontWeight="Bold"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              Margin="520,35,0,0"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              Width="75"
                              Height="25">
                </ToggleButton>
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger SourceName="DetailsButton"
                         Property="IsChecked"
                         Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Height"
                            Value="100" />
                </Trigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

I have changed `Button` to a `ToggleButton` so it can have two states and also shows clear indications.

in the trigger i have set the height to 100 when the button is checked. and it will be reverted back once the condition become false

see if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: better approach than mine, pure XAML.